# Escaping unicode surrogate characters?

Tags: java, unicode, escaping, unicode-escapes

I have the following line of text (see in code as well:

[**TEXT**](http://puu.sh/7ZS02.png)

What I'm trying to do do is escape that emoticon (phone icon) as two \u chars then back to its original phone icon?  The first method below works fine but I essentially want to escape by a range so that I can escape any chars like this.  I don't know how this is possible using the first method below.

How can I achieve this range based escape using the UnicodeEscaper as the same output as StringEscapeUtils (i.e. escape to two \uxx \uxx then unescape back to phone icon)?

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.text.translate.UnicodeEscaper;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.text.translate.UnicodeUnescaper;

    String text = "Unicode surrogate here-> <--here";
    // escape the entire string...not what I want because there could
    // be \n \r or any other escape chars that I want left in tact (i just want  a range)
    String text2 = org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(text);
    System.out.println(text2);   // "Unicode surrogate here-> \uD83D\uDCF1<--here"
    // unescape it back to the phone emoticon
    text2 = org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(text);
    System.out.println(text2); // "Unicode surrogate here-> <--here"

    // How do I do the same as above but but looking for a range of chars to escape (i.e. any unicode surrogate)
    // , which is what i want  and not to escape the entire string
    text2 = UnicodeEscaper.between(0x10000, 0x10FFFF).translate(text);
    System.out.println(text2); // "Unicode surrogate here-> \u1F4F1<--here"
    // unescape .... (need the phone emoticon here)
    text2 = (new UnicodeUnescaper().translate(text2));
    System.out.println(text2);// "Unicode surrogate here-> ὏1<--here"
```

Comment: What is `UnicodeEscaper`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your string:

```
"Unicode surrogate here-> \u1F4F1<--here"
```

does not do what you think it does.

A `char` is basically a UTF-16 code unit, therefore 16 bits. So what happens here is that you have `\u1f41 1`; and that explains your output.

I don't know what you call "escape" here, but if this is replacing surrogate pairs by "\u\u", then have a look at `Character.toChars()`. It will return the `char` sequence necessary to represent one Unicode code point, whether it is in the BMP (one char) or not (two chars).

For code point U+1f4f1, it will return a two-element char array with characters 0xd83d and 0xdcf1 in that order. And this is what you want.

Comment: thx, makes sense, However, for my use case I'm not keeping track of what can "be escaped" to \uxxx.  There could be dozens of these chars.  So, now I need to figure out how to convert back to the original text without persisting these and running toChar() on each.

Comment: Well no, it's not working since your escape sequence for characters outside the BMP is wrong ;) Also, for whom/what do you escape?

Comment: i want to escape a range of all surrogates.

Comment: Using what exactly? The representation you currently use (`\uxxxxxx`) is not directly mappable to `char`. You'd need to read everything after `\u` that is a hexadecimal digit and convert to a `char[]`, with room for errors too (how do you interpret `\u11111`? U+1111 and '1' or U+11111?)

Answer (score 3):

Too late answer. But I've found you need

```
org.apache.commons.lang3.text.translate.JavaUnicodeEscaper
```

class instead UnicodeEscaper.

Using it, it prints:

```
Unicode surrogate here-> \uD83D\uDCF1<--here
```

And the unescaping works well.